# How do you interpolate values on a time series to get a function (equation)?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, numerical-linear-algebra, interpolation

I have following time series:

```
1   10000
2   
3
4   20000
5   
6   
7
8   
9   
10  
11  
12
13  
14  
15  
16  200000
```

And I need to interpolate those values to get the rest of them.
How do I do that?

Comment: We have to know which sort of functions you want to use to interpolate the values. There are a lot of possibilities: quadratic functions, exponential functions, piecewise linear functions etc. Do we know anything about the origin of the data? Is there any physical background that tells us which sort of functions would be appropriate?

Comment: @ReinhardMeier Thanks for the comment. I want to use exponential function.

Comment: Do you want to have a function that fits the data exactly? In case of three values, you usually need functions with three parameters, e.g. $f(x)=ae^{bx}+c.$ Is this what you are looking for? Or do you want to have a "close" fit with functions like $f(x)=ae^{bx}$ that only fits the data as well as possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments, it sounds like what you want is a best-fit (as opposed to exact-fit) exponential function. The usual approach to this would be as follows:

Note that if $x,y$ values followed (exactly) the relationship $y = ae^{bx}$, then we would have
$$
y = ae^{bx} \implies \log(y) = \ln(a) + bx \leadsto z = a_0 + bx.
$$
In other words, the variables $x$ and $z = \ln(y)$ satisfy the relationship $a_0 + bx$ for some numbers $a_0,b$.  These numbers would have to satisfy the equation
$$
\pmatrix{1&1\\1&4\\1&16} \pmatrix{a_0\\b} = \pmatrix{\ln(10000)\\ \ln(20000)\\ \ln(200000)}.
$$
As it turns out, this equation has no exact solution. However, we can obtain the least-squares solution by solving the associated equation
$$
\pmatrix{1&1\\1&4\\1&16}^T\pmatrix{1&1\\1&4\\1&16} \pmatrix{a_0\\b} = \pmatrix{1&1\\1&4\\1&16}^T\pmatrix{\ln(10000)\\ \ln(20000)\\ \ln(200000)}.
$$
Solving this equation leads to the answer $a_0 = 9.0576, b = 0.1975$. The associated value $a$ is given by
$$
\ln(a) = a_0 \implies a = e^{a_0} = 8583.5,
$$
which leads to the best-fit model
$$
y = 8583.5 \cdot e^{0.1975 \cdot x}.
$$